# Ionic long press event on cards

Tags: ionic-framework

How can I set a long press event to a card in Ionic to fire up action sheet for the specific card. Just help me in binding this long press event in ionic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-long-press

This plugin should be compatible with `Ionic` and `Angular 7+`

Import the module:

```
import { LongPressModule } from 'ionic-long-press';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        LongPressModule
        ...
    ]
})
```

And use in your template:

```
<button
  ion-button
  ion-long-press
  [interval]="400"
  (pressed)="pressed()"
  (longPressed)="active()"
  (pressEnded)="released()"
></button>
```

Answer (score 6):

Ionic 4 Gestures:
Install HammerJs.

```
npm install hammerjs
```

Inside:  `src/main.ts`

```
/**
 * Hammerjs must be imported for gestures
 */
import 'hammerjs';
```

You can do something like:

```
<ion-card (press)="tapEvent($event)">
  <ion-item>
    Tapped: {{tap}} times
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

In .ts

```
tapEvent(e){
    console.log(e);
    this.tap++;
}
```

Comment: There are issues using Hammerjs with Ionic 4 => https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19183

Comment: Thank you so much. This saved me a lot!