# Press event is not fired on Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to implement multiple select on multiple items (a list of `ion-item-sliding`) when one of them is pressed for few seconds by adding `(press)` to each `ion-item-sliding` and it seems that the press event is never fired. I moved the press event to `ion-item` but nothing still happened. Then I tried to test directly the press event on a `ion-button` and found out that the press event is the problem because when I change it to click it's working perfectly. Here is what I tried:

```
<ion-button (press)="itemPressed()">Test</ion-button>
```

```
itemPressed() {
    console.log("expecting to work");
}
```

Comment: Do you want to implement long press in ionic button?

Comment: Not on ionic button but on ```ion-item-sliding``` :) I used ionic button here only to show that the press event is not fired

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Arj 1411's answer add  `HammerModule` in  '@angular/platform-browser' imports and this should be work.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was the missing piece

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the tap and click event as mentioned below instead of using press.

```
<ion-button (click)="itemPressed()">Test</ion-button>
```

or

```
<ion-button tappable (tap)="itemPressed()">Test</ion-button>
```

if you want to use the long press event. there is NPM plugin avilable on below url you can use that.. this could help you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-long-press

[Ionic long press event on cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995177/ionic-long-press-event-on-cards)

Comment: Thanks for the answer first. I tried ```tappable (tap)``` but it does not trigger anything too and I cannot use click because I want to multiple select items only when one of the items is long pressed.

Comment: can you please show me .. how does your select box looks .. how do you want to select multiple items.. basically you want long press event with ionic5 correct ?

Comment: Thanks for the links. I tested it and it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can implement long press with `Hammer.js`

1.install Hammer.js from `npm install hammerjs — save`

2.on `src/main.ts` file make changes like following

```
 import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
    import { environment } from './environments/environment';
    **import "hammerjs";** 
    
    if (environment.production) {
      enableProdMode();
    }
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

3.on your template and component file

```
<ion-button (press)="onPress($event)" (pressup)="onPressUp($event)"> Test </ion-button>

onPress($event) {
    console.log("onPress", $event);
}

onPressUp($event) {
    console.log("onPressUp", $event);
}
```

Try this. If this is not working as expected let me know. I will edit my answer

Comment: I've tried this a an hour ago from this link https://medium.com/madewithply/ionic-4-long-press-gestures-96cf1e44098b but still nothing happened.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add what have you tried?

Comment: I can see you are using (press) instead of (pressup).

Comment: I copy pasted code from the link too but nothing worked. HammerModule was missing from the import. Thanks for the trouble sir.

Comment: Its Ok. If you find answer as suitable please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, for Ionic 6, this probably is the best option

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-5-long-press-gesture-example/188746/7

It works like a charm and you don't need to install any module.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is actually to use the `contextmenu` event instead of `press`. This is natively supported and so will not need HammerJS (or anything else).